# How to add all leaves of a tree to a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, tree, ldap

I am currently writing some code that searches the Active Directory via some LDAP queries. I have come to a situation where I have an object of type `Principal`, this is either `GroupPrincipal` or `UserPrincipal`. However, if it is a `GroupPrincipal` it might contain objects of type `UserPrincipal`. I would like extract all items of type `UserPrincipal` to a list so that I can perform some other procedures on them.

I imagine that can be done using trees but am not sure how.

Here is a code I wrote that is ineffective, only goes two nodes deep and prints the names rather than adding them to a list:

```
foreach (var principal in group.GetMembers())
{
    if (principal is UserPrincipal)
    {
        var uPrincipal = principal as UserPrincipal;
        Console.WriteLine("User: " + uPrincipal.Name);
    }
    else if (principal is GroupPrincipal)
    {
        var gPrincipal = principal as GroupPrincipal;
        Console.WriteLine("Group: " + gPrincipal.Name);
        foreach(var principalito in gPrincipal.GetMembers())
        {
            if (principalito is UserPrincipal)
            {
                var uPrincipalito = principalito as UserPrincipal;
                Console.WriteLine(">>User: " + uPrincipalito.Name);
            }
            else if(principalito is GroupPrincipal)
            {
                var gPrincipalito = principalito as GroupPrincipal;
                Console.WriteLine(">>Group: " + gPrincipalito.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I belive you can use the method : GroupPrincipal.GetMembers(true) and then just check if it is of the type UserPrincipal and then add it to a list.

Comment: Yes, but what if the member is a Group itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void getAllUserPrinicpals(ref List<UserPrincipal> principals, GroupPrincipal principal)
    {
        if (principal != null)
        {
            foreach (Principal princ in principal.GetMembers(true))
            {
                if (princ is UserPrincipal)
                    principals.Add((UserPrincipal)princ);
                else if (princ is GroupPrincipal)
                    getAllUserPrinicpals(ref principals, (GroupPrincipal)princ);
            }
        }
    }
```